# Vue and API: Displaying Image

Tags: html, image, api, vue.js, vue-component

I am currently using Vue JS and the data is coming from API .
to call a data from API I use this method {{services.service_picture}}.

But the problem is I am unable to display the image with this method below.
Can you please send some ideas on how to display it using Vue JS

```html
<div id="main" v-cloak>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p v-for="picture in services.service_picture"></p>
    <img :src="path + '/images/services/'+ picture" class="img-circle" alt="Services" /> </div>
</div>
```

```js
var main = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    services: [],
    path: 'https://examplemyapisource.com'
  },
});
```

```html
API from https://examplemyapisource.com
[ 
  { "service_picture": "18_1516090191.jpg", } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You try here:

```
<div id="main" v-cloak>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p v-for="picture in services"></p>
    <img :src="path + '/images/services/'+ picture.service_picture" class="img-circle" alt="Services" /> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you .I made some adjustments then it displayed the image

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Huang Hong

```html
<img :src="path+'/images/services/'+services.service_picture" class="img-circle" alt="Services">
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the your v-for only includes the

element, therfore you cannot use 'picture' inside the  element.

```
<p v-for="picture in services.service_picture"></p>
<img :src="path + '/images/services/'+ picture" class="img-circle" alt="Services" />
```

Comment: Yes. I changed it

Comment: <img :src="path+'/images/services/'+ services.service_picture" class="img-circle" >

Answer (score 0):

You need to make these changes to get a perfect image.
Here you closed the `<p>` tag before the image.close that `<p>` tag after image

```
<div id="main" v-cloak>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
   <p v-for="picture in services">
      <img :src="path + '/images/services/'+ picture.service_picture" class="img-circle" alt="Services" /> </div>
   </p>
</div>
```