# How to save image link in when using 'require' to display image in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to create a page where I show Pizza items with their images. The Pizza object is saved in the DB with a field `imgUrl`. The image is not getting displayed but I see the `alt` text that I provided but I can see in the console that the image link is correct.

Right now, the imgUrl field in the database has data like `../assets/images/pizza.jpg`. Should I instead save `require(../assets/images/pizza.jpg)` in the db. That looks weird. Here is the code, please look at the mounted method.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="class">
      <span><h1>All you can eat Menu.</h1></span>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box" v-for="item in pizzaList" :key="item.id">
          <div>
            <img :src="item.imgUrl" alt="Image"/>
              <div>
                <a class="btn" @mouseenter="$event.currentTarget.style.background = '#EF6B7F'"
                @mouseleave="$event.currentTarget.style.background = '#e31837' ">Buy Now</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      pizzaList: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8081/api/pizza/all')
    .then(response => {
      this.pizzaList = response.data;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I have already read
[Vue and API: Displaying Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182984/vue-and-api-displaying-image)
[Image path in Vue JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352923/image-path-in-vue-js)
[How to reference static assets within vue javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313165/how-to-reference-static-assets-within-vue-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but what these answers are telling is how to do when we have hardcoded the url, we should encapsulate it with `require` but they do not tell when we are getting the link from the DB, how do we put `require` in the html tag.
I hope my question was clear. Please ask for details if you need. thanks

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64208406/381282

Comment: Yes, it is Vue CLI. it worked. thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working was because

`Webpack's require() needs at least some part of the file path to be completely static and we should "make only part of the path dynamic"`

that means you cannot put the entire image path in the DB and in the UI pass it to `require` and expect it to work

I replaced

```
<img :src="require(`${item.imgUrl}`)" alt="Image"/>
```

where item.imgUrl = '`../assets/entities/pizza/pizza_1.jpg`'    (which is the entire image path relative to the component)

by

```
<img :src="require(`../assets${item.imgUrl}`)" alt="Image"/>
```

where item.imgUrl = '`/entities/pizza/pizza_1.jpg`'

This answer mentioned by `Michal Levy` up in the comments explains all this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64208406/8147680